# Is it fine to ask about commercial software library?

Tags: discussion, questions

In [vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaadin) some of the libraries are paid (*initially available for 30-day trial*). I saw [vaadin-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaadin-chart) and [vaadin-touchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaadin-touchkit) tags. Moreover, vaadin testbench is also *paid* but we do not have tag for it. I had take a look in [CVAL3](https://vaadin.com/license/cval-3) but it does not state anything about it. Though, I don't know much about license agreement clauses. There may be other tags that are based on commercial libraries.

My questions are,

- To what extent can we discuss it on Stack Overflow?
- Isn't it against the license agreement?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes people ask questions about this commercial software called Windows. You have to pay for it, but it still seems to be relatively popular.

Comment: I see your NDA and I raise you my shart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a programming-related problem, you can just ask the question. It doesn't matter if you happen to be using a library.

Basically the only library-related subject you can't ask here, is what library to use.

What kind of license agreement would forbid their users from asking programming-related questions? None that I heard of. (NDA aside)

Comment: That being said, if your question is about a paid library, chances someone will happen to be using that library and can answer drop **a lot**